# Fitted values and weights in tensorflow (tesorflow DNNRegressor)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow version 2.0.0-beta1. I have created the input function to feed into tf.estimator.DNNRegressor.

```
input_func = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,
                                                y=y_train,
                                                batch_size=10,
                                                num_epochs=1000,
                                                shuffle=True)
```

Below is the model that I am creating using DNNRegressor.

```
model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_col, hidden_units=[1024, 800, 512, 256])
model.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=10000)
```

Now I want to identify

**1) Fitted values of my model on training data.**

**2) Weights associated with each variable in model(i.e. tf.estimator.DNNRegressor)**

I have search through the documentation of tensorflow and other sources but didn't get this information.